# What does "clockwise" mean, exactly?

Tags: rotation, conventions, chirality

I am in the middle of a discussion with a friend about the meaning of the term "clockwise".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwise) indicates that a clockwise rotation goes as **top-right-down-left**.

However, my friend argues that "the clock is facing opposite to you. So if you rotate top-right-down-left facing the side the clock is facing then it is anti-clockwise."

Our question, therefore, is

> does "clockwise" mean **top-right-down-left** or **left-down-right-top**?

Comment: Please add reason for downvote!

Comment: They both look clockwise to me. Note, if you go to the other side of the plane, then clockwise and anticlockwise will change. (e.g. Earth is rotating anticlockwise around it self if you live in the northern hemisphere, but not in the southern hemisphere).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about English terminology having nothing to do with physics.

Comment: I agree with Chris White. Conventions aren't physics. It is just English. But I won't downvote... ( P.S. This version (v4) is much better than the previous version, which may be the reason for me not to downvote. )

Comment: I disagree. "Clockwise" is an important, ubiquitous technical term in the physical literature, and it is perfectly fine to have questions about their specific meaning and the conventions that surround such technical terms. Conventions are not physical _insight_ but they are a crucial part of transmitting and understanding it.

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4627/cmon-lets-rescue-the-clockwise-question).

Comment: FWIW I disagree with @Emilio - I would not consider "clockwise" to be a technical term in physics. Just an ordinary English term. That being said, I don't think this question is egregiously or obviously off topic in the sense that some others are, so I wouldn't mind _that_ much if it were open.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [clockwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clockwise) direction is normally defined by the [right hand grip rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule#Direction_associated_with_a_rotation).

[image: Clockwise]

When your thumb is pointing away from you, your fingers are curled clockwise. So when you look at a clock the axis of rotation is away from you through the clock.

I'd guess the downvotes are because people believe your question is not physics related, but in fact this rule is how you determine the direction of the angular momentum vector, so there is a connection with physics.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Do you have any comment on my friends theory? The clock is actually facing opposite to you. So when you rotate your finger in TOP-RIGHT-DOWN-LEFT direction as clock's needle its anti-clockwise. One other similar example is when you shake your hands to opposite person, you shake you right hand to other person's right hand not the left hand.

Comment: Your friend is sort of correct. As observed by the person looking at the clock the clock hands are rotating clockwise. If you imagine youself as the clock, looking out through the clock face then you'd observe the hands to be rotating counter-clockwise. However there is no special significance to this. It's just a convention about what you take to be the direction of the axis.

Comment: @Madhu: "my friends theory". Uhhh,... How is that a [theory](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68599/what-sets-a-law-apart-from-a-rule-or-a-principle/68601#68601)?

Comment: Well, Its just a concept what he is thinking :-)

Comment: @Madhu: In future please reply to a user by using "@username", as I  have done here as an example. Else, they won't be notified. For example, to reply to me,  "@Dimension10", etc.

Comment: A down vote? What on Earth was that for? This answer seems to me thoroughly uncontroversial.

Comment: Apologies, John. On first sight it looked the wrong way round, but now I think it is just very confusing. I think very few people would put their right thumb pointing _into_ the wall.

Comment: So the next question is *what does "right" mean, exactly?*. ;)

Comment: After spending far too much time on this, because I assumed you were
after something deeper, which I attempted to understand and check, I
think that your answer is only simply adding confusion.  You are
replacing one simple object (the clock) that has a single way to be
looked at by another (the hand) that exists in two chiral variants and
has no natural viewing angle (more accurately, the viewing angle you
use is not the natural one). You confused @Emilio, and you confused
me even more. Explanation should reduce to simpler concepts, not to
more complex ones.

Comment: @babou Actually, it is possible to unambiguously define right-handedness in terms of observations of elementary particle decays. It is however, easier just to assume a standard human who know his right from left unless circumstances really prevent that.

Comment: @dmckee Your remark is of a fundamental physical nature. We can defined
handedness (and that includes clockwise rotation) from natural
phenomena that are not arbitrarily oriented. The discussion was about
the proper means to define clockwise rotation, and I simply said that
using human hands just made it more complicated than using a clock,
without any benefit. I
did not deny that one form of chirality can be explained in terms of
another one, nor that there may be natural phenomena that can define
chirality because their chiral twin is missing.

Comment: There are people who are unable to tell their right hand from their left. (They do exist, I've met some of them.) How would you explain the right-hand rule to them?

Comment: I'd just want a change. An axis of rotation *doesn't have a direction*. It doesn't point away or toward you when you look at a clock. The angular momentum vector does (conventionally) have a direction, which is as you say.

All in all, this question was made way more complicated than it should be. Clockwise is a convention, and it's the direction the hands turn when you look at a clock (as people usually don't look from inside a clock).

Answer (score 7):

Your confusion arises because the term (anti)clockwise, when used by itself, is ambiguous, and should always be used with a statement like "as seen from the top" (unless that is absolutely obvious$^1$). The reason for this is that "clockwise" defines a direction of rotation within a plane, but does not specify which side the plane is observed from. (In more technical language, "clockwise" defines an order for two basis vectors for the plane, but does not specify a sign for the normal.) If you take a transparent clock mounted on a glass window, it will rotate clockwise or anticlockwise depending on what side of the window you're standing.

That said, a statement like "clockwise as seen from the top" is not ambiguous. This refers to the direction of rotation of the hands of a (normal, non-transparent) clock as *you* observe them. It coincides with the direction your fingers point to when you put your **left** hand in front of you with your thumb pointing towards you. In your terms,

> clockwise means "top-right-down-left".

Additionally, if the question is purely about a planar problem (i.e. when doing 2D analytical geometry), then there *is* a canonical way to understand the term. Put the page on the wall so you can read it, next to a clock whose face you can see; its hands will move clockwise. This is equivalent to setting the plane normal "up", towards you. Put your left hand on the page with your thumb toward you, and your fingers will be clockwise.

It must also be noted that the "positive" direction of rotation is usually defined to be anticlockwise. Given a directed axis, put your *right* hand with your thumb pointing along the axis in the given direction, and then your fingers will point to the "positive" direction of rotation.

<sub>$^1$One example of this is hurricanes, which are said to rotate (anti)clockwise in the (northern) southern hemisphere. Here of course you're supposed to look at them from above (e.g. from space). If you see one from the ground (preferably from the eye, and from inside a well-protected building) the rotation will be inverted.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Apparently, there seems to be no agreed upon definition of clockwise in 3D space - but an a clear agreement regarding the meaning in a plane "seen from above"**

As I am starting to answer, I have no idea what is the correct answer,
if any. It is the "if any" that gets me started on this topic. I am
certainly not an expert, I never could tell my left from my right,
especially after having physics classes, but I am looking for the
available evidence.

To be honest I got actually very confused by John Rennie's answers, because I did not see the need to introduce yet another device, which you have to orient like the first, but not so naturally ... At least there is only one kind of clocks (except for funny souvenirs), while there are two kinds of hands to add to confusion. Also there is only one natural way to look at a clock, while there is no specific or normalized way to look at your hand, though having the thumb first is the natural position ... !

The word "clockwise" is used more than 800 times on physics.stackexchange.com
according to the very approximative figures of google (I used:
*clockwise site:physics.stackexchange.com*). This adverb must have some
relevance to physics.

When searching the web, or wikipedia, for a formal definition of
(counter-)clockwise in 3D, there seems to be none to be found. the answer by @Emilio is close to mine as he does seem to consider that the adverb "*clockwise*" has a well defined meaning without further precision.

The Internet being somewhat too large a place for me, I looked at
the uses of this adverb on physics.stackexchange.com. I even limited
myself to the first twenty answers from Google, as this takes
considerable time. Be my guest to do more.

Many uses are simply informal. Wich way does this or that turn when
you (un)screw or look at its rotation (like a clock). Bicycle pedals
is a good example. In many other cases, it is only used to indicate
changes in the sign of angular velocity, with corresponding changes in
the sign of other quantities, without any precise chiral information.
Note, for example, qthat when talking of hurricanes, it is always rotation as seen from above, like a clock seen from the front.

In [Vector Nature Of Angular Velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44773), the use is
clearly a 2D planar use, about a plane seen from above. The vector
considered does follow the right-hand rule. But it is not construed as
a definition of clock-wise rotation in 3-D.

The same is true in [Alkali atom in oscilating electromagnetic field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48600). Indeed, it talks of counter-clockwise rotation as it look at the right
hand from the end of the thumb.

In the answer to question
[What is negative angular acceleration?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48466), things are a bit
confused as it mentions the right hand rule, but seems to describe the
opposite.  Then it also defines clockwise as the positive rotation,
while it is usually considered negative in mathematics (well, it did
in my school times, but I would not know the current fads). Again,
this is not construed as a definition of clockwise in 3D.

Question [Lenz' law versus $-\frac{d\Omega}{dt}$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13912) uses
"*clockwise (using right-hand notation)*". The answer too makes
explicit reference to the right hand rule to define *clockwise*.

One answer to [Applying the right-hand rule for magnetic forces](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68855)
explicitly uses the right hand rule, and explains that it is useful
because the direction is "*counter-clockwise or clockwise depending on
what side of the plane you are looking at*".

One thing in common to all the uses where it matters is that the
authors do not seem to think that there is an agreed upon definition
of (counter-)clockwise in 3D which they can rely on for unambiguous
communication.

The other thing in common (except maybe for the third)
is that seem all to understand clockwise as "like a clock seen from above", when you use the right hand rule to translate what is being said.

Based of this evidence, admittedly needing more investigation,
my own **temporary conclusion** is that, unless someone can point to an
"official" and agreed upon definition of the concept of clockwise rotation in 3D,
it is probably inappropriate to assume such a definition.

The **other conclusion** is that there is clear consensus that clockwise means, in a plane, like a clock arms in the same plane assuming the clock is facing you.

An interesting aspect of it is that the word (counter-)clockwise seems
very much used because it has intuitive meaning, apparently more than
the right-hand rule. But it has sometimes to be defined more
precisely, by the right-hand rule or equivalent means (you look at a
clock in the XY plane from the positive Z ...).

Another clear conclusion, at least to me, is that it is an
appropriate question, and it should be upvoted. It may not
be physics in the most basic sense, but it is obviously a tool for the
physicist, and without proper tools technicians cannot work.

Comment: @JohnRennie  Sorry for the error. The problem is that other answers are hidden when I edit, so that I have to rely on my deficient memory.

Comment: This is not entirely true. Experiments on the decay of neutral kaons (to take one instance) can be analyzed to provide *both* an absolute definition of anit- versus normal-matter and an absolute definition of right- versus left-handedness. From there we simple note that clockwise is "into the wall" by the right-hand rule. (Historically of course we established these things by reference to ourselves, but we can now communicate both ideas to a distance correspondent who we can not meet, and they will know what we mean despite not being able to check the original referents).

Comment: @dm All I said is that clockwise rotation has no
well defined meaning in 3D, and the right had rule is really the only
useful concept. I never said there is no absolute definition of
handedness. I think the "explanation" by John Rennie
introduced confusion in the issue discussed, and I first thought he
was trying to generalize clockwiseness to a substitute for the
left hand rule. So I check whether there was anything of the kind in
what people write. I protested the use of hands rather than clock, not
of a relation between the rotation of a clock (which is chiral) with
other chiral definitions

Comment: @babou: at the time I posted the question was attracting a lot of downvotes, and the main aim was to show that it wasn't a completely silly question, there was some relation to physics, and hopefully stop further downvotes (in this I was successful! :-). With the comments and your answer the discussion has moved on to the question of handedness in physics, which is beyond what I saw as the scope of the question.

Comment: @John Thanks. Actually I did not want to discuss chirality in
physics. Dmckee misread me, as much as I misread you. I did not say a wrong
word in that respect, afaik. I try to write
carefully. I had the same purpose as you, and even upvoted OP. A
very similar question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2702
was treated decently. There is no reason it should have been different
here. I did a real job of analyzing the use of chirality mnemonics,
even though your answer had confused me, and all I got was a downvote
for an unknown reason. Complete failure for all, moderators too.