# I want to know more about this specific perpetuum mobile

Tags: energy-conservation, dissipation, perpetual-motion

Sorry for beeing another noob asking stupid questions, but I just wanna know more about this specific perpetuum mobile.
[What prevents this magnetic perpetuum mobile from working?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75471/what-prevents-this-magnetic-perpetuum-mobile-from-working)
I don t say I full understand the math, but I cant disagree with something that history proved that is alwasy right.
I just want that someone explain and draw for me the balanced state of the system which I can t find jow hard i would try.
Srry for my English, I am not a native speaker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What prevents this magnetic perpetuum mobile from working?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75471/)

Comment: What is exactly what you want to know that it is not on the answer?

Comment: Hi, posibly that my stupid question or my 3rd world english does not make the things clear enough. I would like a schematics that represents that rotating system reach the forces equilibrum or something to explain me, like to a child, why this mechanism is not a perpetuum. I know that this does not work in real life and I am not that stupid to disagree with the law of conservation energy, but I simply miss something, I can t understant, probably my missleading knowladge of physics.