# If the axis of rotation is fixed, is it ok to say clockwise torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, soft-question, rotational-dynamics, terminology, torque

I know that the direction of torque is along the axis of rotation, but would it be acceptable to say, for example considering a vertical thin rod in the x-y plane with a force acting on the bottom end towards the left, 'it is a clockwise torque about the centre of mass' (even though strictly speaking the torque's direction is into the page?)

It just seems to me easier to describe what's happening that way.

Comment: In fact when you do statics, you start by counting up all the resulting torques as +CCW and -CW, so just saying _clockwise_ automatically means a negative value. Only in statics though, because the sum of moments is the same regardless of the point of reference. In dynamics, you must choose torques about the center of mass, _always_.

Comment: I would usually add "as seen from..." but in your case it seems to be fine.

Comment: @ja72 I'm a little confused when you say, 'In dynamics, you must choose torques about the centre of mass, _always_.' What about if the rod is hinged about the other end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the situation you gave, it's immediately clear what is meant, and there's no possibility for misinterpretation, so yes, it's perfectly acceptable. (Remember that torque is mathematically defined as a vector for convenience, but the *direction* of that vector isn't really physical.)

The only issue I can see with that is that as you leave the simple two-dimensional world and start looking at more complex problems, you've quickly need to abandon that way of describing things, since "clockwise" and "counter-clockwise" are a lot harder to keep track of.

Comment: Thanks. I presume the same would apply to other rotational quantities such as angular velocity (actually, in my lecture notes, sometimes the diagrams do have a curved arrow labelled with omega, when I think about it)

Comment: Compare to http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/71455/what-does-clockwise-mean-exactly. Just because you are perfectly clear on what you mean does not imply that your listener is perfectly clear on what you mean. In order for "clockwise" to be clear you have to be have agreed on a "forward" first.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on the situation I guess. In my example I don't really see how someone could misinterpret it as a clockwise torque from the other side of the x-y plane

Comment: Yes, that's why it's clear here. Pedagogically, I'd avoid it to avoid issues when adding a third dimension.